# How to implement multi-level hierarchies in user management

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Implement multi-level hierarchies so that super user have also all rights that sub user have means super user can also manage sub-users jobs.

Suppose in Application there can be N number of user hierarchies...

- Super User

  - Sub User

    - Sub User -1

e.g So Sub user is super user for sub user-1 . This way sub user would handle all jobs of his super user.

How to design the database for this.

Comment: Please be more specific, and proofread your question.

Comment: I hope someone can understand this, because i can't

Comment: Is it a business requirement that you do his from scratch or can you consider existing solutions? Like LDAP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is a ACL libary.

ACL stands for Access Control List. it uses 2 "sub models" called ARO and ACO.

Aro's are what is "requesting the data" - e.g. the user/group (and can be structured as a tree using nested sets, or a simple recursive tree [parent_id]).

Aco's are what is being requested - a certain model, a page, a function - what ever.

then you combine the two (aco and aro) to create the ACL - basicly saying "this user/group can/can't use this model/page"

According to your tags i see you're looking for a PHP/MySQL solution - so phpGACL might be very helpful to you: http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/

Its a complete "framework" for managing ACL's which you can easily combine into your application (how ever its structured).

Hope that helped you out a bit - or atleast pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Nice answer, and nice of you to take the time to attack a question that appears to have confused many.  My only problem with phpGACL is that it was last update over 3 years ago, know any alternatives or PHP5 equivalents?

Comment: Thank you, i guess this is what stack overflow is all about.
well googling "phpGACL php5" raise this topic which might push you in the right direction:
http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=152966
(the first post)

Comment: To bad he/she didn't even have the decency to select your answer.